# Python, Disnake дискорд бот

Tags: python, discord

Хочу сделать бан определенного пользователя с причиной на слеш-командах
Вот что пробовал:

```
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",
                   intents=disnake.Intents.all(),
                   activity=disnake.Game("PyCharm"),
                   status=disnake.Status.do_not_disturb)

bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.slash_command(name="бан", description="Банит участника")
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(inter, member: disnake.Member, *, reason="Нарушение правил"):
    embed = disnake.Embed(
        title="Модерация",
        color=0x3c36d3,
        description=f"Администратор {inter.author.mention} забанил участника {member.name}"
    )
    await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    await member.ban()

bot.run("Токен")
```

Comment: А в чём собственно заключается ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых в аргументах slash-команды вам не понадобится `*`

Во-вторых ваш аргумент `reason` нигде не используется. В строке `await member.ban()` задайте аргумент `reason=reason`.

**Итог:**

```
@bot.slash_command(name="бан", description="Банит участника")
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(inter, member: disnake.Member, reason="Нарушение правил"):
    embed = disnake.Embed(
        title="Модерация",
        color=0x3c36d3,
        description=f"Администратор {inter.author.mention} забанил участника {member.name}"
    )
    await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
```